# Avoid multiple DOCTYPE and html tags when using ui:include

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

we are using several `ui:include` tags in the "main" page. The page that is to be included looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=".." xmlns:ui="..." ...>
    <ui:fragment rendered="${foo}">
       some html code
    </ui:fragement>
    <ui:fragment rendered="${!foo || bar}">
       some more html code
    </ui:fragement>
</html>
```

Using the `ui:include` for templating results in repeating the `DOCTYPE` and `html` tag several times in the source code, which is pretty ugly. (Sure, the user doesn't see, but I'm a fan of tidy html)

However, if I remove the `DOCTYPE` and `html` tag from the to-be-included-xhtml, the Faces Servlet throws an exception stating that the prefix `ui` for `ui:fragment` is not bound.

Does anybody know, how I can include another XHTML page **without** the multiple `DOCTYPE`s and `html`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the ui:composition tag.
We also use ui:include to include jsf2 pages, and to solve the problem you have I believe you could alter your included page by adding the ui:composition tag as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=".." xmlns:ui="..." ...>
    <ui:composition>
    <ui:fragment rendered="${foo}">
       some html code
    </ui:fragement>
    <ui:fragment rendered="${!foo || bar}">
       some more html code
    </ui:fragement>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```